# Capacitance of a parallel plate capacitor with another metal plate connected diagonally

Tags: capacitance

[image: 1]

What would be the capacitance of such a configuration between the terminals ?

Comment: Should it be called a capacitor ? All the ends are connected so looks like it just a metallic conductor. Though I am not very sure, but I can't think of any contradiction to what I first thought.

Comment: This community appreciates the mention of what was your process or to tell how you tried to solve your asked question and mention in specific manner where you got stuck.

Comment: The capacitance is infinite but the breakdown voltage is zero.